# Spurious microwave emissions perhaps coming from conducting TRIAC controlling AC power?

Tags: triac, microwave, emissions

I have a TRIAC switch on an 240VAC single phase AC line.  There is voltage on the gate as specified, there is a small dead band near zero.  I.e. it is conducting as expected.

However, I'm picking up spurious emissions in the ~6 GHz range. Is it possible that this is coming from the TRIAC switch circuit?

Has anyone measured a spectrum, using an instrument that measures out to that range, of that AC waveform with the dead band?  Are there residuals that high in frequency?

Would a reactive load with a conducting TRIAC somehow cause it to ring?  Has anyone seen that happen?

Comment: "I'm picking up spurious emissions in the ~6 GHz range" - at what amplitude? Do they go away when the TRIAC isn't turned on?